# node jQuery $.Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I try to run jQuery `$.Deferred` on node.js.

The working code in Browser is

http://jsfiddle.net/vLu35bbu/

```
console = {
    log : function(msg) {
        $("#console").append(msg);
    }
};


var __t = function(time)
{
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) 
    {
        setTimeout(dfd.resolve, time);
    })
    .promise();
}

__t(2000)
.then(function() 
{
    console.log("Hello!");
});
```

So, just trying to migrate to node:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/jquery

```
npm install jquery
```

then

app.js

```
 var $ = require('jquery');

 var __t = function(time)
 {
   return $.Deferred(function(dfd)
     {
       setTimeout(dfd.resolve, time);
     })
     .promise();
 };

 __t(2000)
   .then(function()
   {
     console.log("Hello");
   });
```

The error goes:

```
/....../app.js:5
   return jquery.Deferred(function(dfd)
                 ^
TypeError: Object function ( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                }
                return factory( w );
            } has no method 'Deferred'
    at __t (/....../app.js:5:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/....../app.js:12:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

What do I miss?

Thanks.

---

EDIT

Thanks to the comment, I try to use

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

instead.

However, some error occurred.

```
/Volumes/GD15/gd1/_book_project/app.js:5
   return $.Deferred(function(dfd)
            ^
TypeError: Object function Q(value) {
    // If the object is already a Promise, return it directly.  This enables
    // the resolve function to both be used to created references from objects,
    // but to tolerably coerce non-promises to promises.
    if (isPromise(value)) {
        return value;
    }

    // assimilate thenables
    if (isPromiseAlike(value)) {
        return coerce(value);
    } else {
        return fulfill(value);
    }
} has no method 'Deferred'
    at __t (/Volumes/GD15/gd1/_book_project/app.js:5:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/GD15/gd1/_book_project/app.js:12:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: It seems like jQuery needs a DOM, even if you're using it within Node. Have you tried using a promise library like [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) without jQuery? That should work.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know `q`, which looks smarter choice. However, after I npm installed and required to use `q` instead, I've got an error for my code. Please see the edit. Any idea what's going on? or how to fix.

Comment: The various promise implementations are not drop-in replacements for one another.  You'll need to read the docs on Q to determine how to use it.

Comment: There's also [Bluebird](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird), which in my opinion is better than Q, and native promises as well

Comment: Great. Perhaps, I should start new Question page, but how do you compare Promise/A+ with FRP?

Comment: @KenOKABE: In short, they solve different problems, and can be used together for great good. But yes, you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments!